# Angularjs apply price range filter with button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, onclick, range

I am new into angularjs. I have the price range based on nouislider and couple of products with different prices. I would like to filter them, but only after click on the filter button. 
This is my "slide filter" in html:

```
            <section class="filter-section">
                <h3>Price</h3>
              <form method="get" name="price-filters">
                <span ng-click="price_slider.start = [180, 1400]" class="clear" id="clearPrice" >Clear</span>
                <div class="price-slider">
                    <div id="price-range" ya-no-ui-slider="price_slider"></div>
                  <div class="values group">
                    <!--data-min-val represent minimal price and data-max-val maximum price respectively in pricing slider range; value="" - default values-->
                    <input class="form-control" name="minVal" id="minVal" type="text" ng-model="price_slider.start[0]">
                    <span class="labels">€ - </span>
                    <input class="form-control" name="maxVal" id="maxVal" type="text" ng-model="price_slider.start[1]">
                    <span class="labels">€</span>
                  </div>
                  <input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" ng-click="priceFiltering('filter')" value="Filter">
                </div>
              </form>
            </section>
```

Here is my price slider in controller:

```
$scope.price_slider = {
        start: [180, 1400],
        connect: true,
        step: 1,
        range: {
            min: 10,
            max: 2500
        }
    };
```

And here is my filter in controller:

```
    $scope.priceFiltering = function(command){
    if (command === "filter"){
        $scope.pricefilter = function (product) {
            if ((product.price <= $scope.price_slider.start[1])&&(product.price >= $scope.price_slider.start[0])){
                return product;
            }
        };
        command = "nofilter";
    }   
}
```

I am applying the filter with ng-repeat like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products | filter:pricefilter  | orderBy:propertyName:reverse">...
</div>
```

Right now at the beginning it works as i want. The user choose on price slider values (eg. min 800€ and max 1000€) and when he clicks on filter button it returns the correct products. However when he moves the slider afterwords filter is still active and returns products immediately. I would like to filter the products always only when the filter button is clicked. I think I am close but I just cannot get it work as I want. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small change in the filter function should work.

You are directly referring to `$scope.price_slider.start[0]` and `$scope.price_slider.start[1]` in the filter, instead set these to another scopes in `priceFiltering` function and assign that scopes in the filter.

See the code below:

```
$scope.priceFiltering = function(){
    $scope.minPrice = $scope.price_slider.start[0];
    $scope.maxPrice = $scope.price_slider.start[1];

    $scope.pricefilter = function (product) {
        if ((product.price <= $scope.maxPrice) && (product.price >= $scope.minPrice)){
            return product;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works great :)

Comment: No problem :) I think you can also keep pricefilter function outside the priceFiltering function for better performance.

Comment: You mean define it outside the priceFiltering function and call it inside afterwards?

Comment: Just define it outside, no need of calling it in controller, the **| filter:pricefilter** in your html will take care of the call

Comment: No problem. :) .